# Finding the least square method for an exponential function

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, exponential-function, regression, least-squares

***Given:***

Data:
 \begin{matrix}
  x & y \\
  1 & 37  \\
  2 & 36.25 \\
  3 & 35.41 \\
  4 & 34.91 \\
  5 & 34.52 \\
  6 & 34.45 \\
  7 & 34.4 \\
  8 & 34 \\
  9 & 33.62 \\
  10 & 33.9  \\
 \end{matrix}
The model we are expected to use:
$$EY=\alpha_{0}e^{-\alpha_{1}x}$$
***Task:***

a) linearize the model with the least square method

b) Give a 95% confidence interval for $\alpha_{0}$ and interpret the result.

***Solution:***
 \begin{matrix}
x & y & Y & xY & x^2 \\
0.00 & 37.00 & 3.61 & 3.61 & 1.00  \\
1.00 & 36.25 & 3.59 & 7.18 & 4.00  \\
2.00 & 35.41 & 3.57 & 10.70 & 9.00  \\
3.00 & 34.91 & 3.55 & 14.21 & 16.00  \\
4.00 & 34.52 & 3.54 & 17.71 & 25.00  \\
5.00 & 34.45 & 3.54 & 21.24 & 36.00  \\
6.00 & 34.40 & 3.54 & 24.77 & 49.00  \\
7.00 & 34.00 & 3.53 & 28.21 & 64.00  \\
8.00 & 33.62 & 3.52 & 31.64 & 81.00  \\
9.00 & 33.90 & 3.52 & 35.23 & 100.00  \\
 \end{matrix}

$$EY=\alpha_{0}e^{-\alpha_{1}x}$$
$$\ln EY=\ln a_{0}-x\ln a_{1}$$

I am not sure if I should switch something here:
$$A=\ln a_{1}$$
$$B=\ln a_{0}$$

\begin{matrix}
  A \sum x + n B = \sum Y \\
  A \sum x^{2} + B \sum x = \sum x Y  \\
 \end{matrix}

From our 
system, we get:
$$A= \frac{\sum Y - n B}{\sum x}$$
$$B = \frac{\sum x \sum x Y - \sum Y \sum x^{2}}{\sum x \sum x - \sum x^{2}n} = 3.60264$$
$$A=-0.0094$$
$$B = \ln a_0 = 3.60264 \Longrightarrow e^{3.60264} = a_0 $$
$$A = \ln a_1 = 0.9905$$

and the result is:
$$36.7953 e^{-0.9905x}$$

Our result is very bad, so I must be making a mistake somewhere

\begin{matrix}
result \\
13.37 \\
4.87 \\
1.78 \\
0.65 \\
0.24 \\
0.09 \\
0.03 \\
0.01 \\
0.00 \\
0.00
\end{matrix}

***Question:***

What am I doing wrong? What is the answer?

***Edit***

for 
$$a1 = 0.0094$$
$$a0 = 36.69532469448542$$

The results are realistic:

[array([36.35200477]),
 array([36.01189694]),
 array([35.67497114]),
 array([35.34119761]),
 array([35.01054684]),
 array([34.68298963]),
 array([34.35849703]),
 array([34.03704038]),
 array([33.71859125]),
 array([33.40312152])]

This is correct:

$$B = \ln a_0 = 3.60264 \Longrightarrow e^{3.60264} = a_0=36.694981432443825 $$

I have considered that these are wrong:

$$A = \ln a_1 = 0.9905$$

How it should be:
$$a_1 = -A =  0.009479410327687468$$

Comment: Check your calculations for the value of $\alpha_1$, it should have a much smaller (absolute) value. I get around $\alpha_1\approx 0.009479$. But in any case, the exponential fit is not very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\ln \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x] = \ln \alpha_0 - \alpha_1x = \beta_0 + \beta_1x $.
Hence you estimate $\hat{\beta_0} = \ln \alpha_0 $, so $\hat{\alpha}_0 = e^{\hat{\beta_0}}$ and $\hat{\beta}_1 = - \hat{\alpha}_1$, i.e., $ - \hat{\beta}_1 = \hat{\alpha}_1$.

Note that the predicted values will be biased, hence you should consider to use the estimated values as initial values in a non-linear regression estimation.